# Cannot add foreign key constraint as GUID

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to associate a `FK` as GUID to my table `service_categories`, this is the query:

```
ALTER TABLE `services`
ADD CONSTRAINT `services_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`guid_service_categories`) REFERENCES `service_categories` (`GUID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This is my table structure `service`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `services` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`GUID` char(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`currency` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` text,
`guid_service_categories` char(36) NOT NULL,
`data` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lastUpdated` varchar(36),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `guid_service_categories` (`guid_service_categories`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and this is my `service_categories`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `service_categories` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`GUID` char(36) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
`name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` text,
`data` int(11) NOT NULL,
`lastUpdated` varchar(36),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I get this error:

> Cannot add foreign key constraint

when I execute the alter, what I did wrong? Thanks and happy holiday!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `ON DELETE SET NULL` in the key definition. [From MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> If you specify a SET NULL action, make sure that you have not declared
>   the columns in the child table as NOT NULL.

You cannot use `SET NULL` on `ON DELETE` if the column cannot be NULL by definition.

If you change the alter statement to RESTRICT or CASCADE:

```
ALTER TABLE `services`
ADD CONSTRAINT `services_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`guid_service_categories`) REFERENCES `service_categories` (`GUID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

or the column definition to allow NULL values, it will work.

Comment: You mean the field GUID of which table?

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito - in your `services` table, you have `guid_service_categories char(36) NOT NULL` - but then you tell the system when setting up the foreign key from this column "set it to `NULL`"